# Run a shell script in a console session without saving it to file

Tags: shell, here-document

I have a question about shell scripting on Linux. I am trying to run this:

```
$ sh << EOF
#!/bin/sh

function test {
echo test
echo test2
}

test


EOF
```

The result is:

```
test
test2
```

But what if I want to run the script with arguments and without saving it to a file?

```
$ sh  $1 test1 test2 << EOF
#!/bin/sh

function test {
echo $2
echo $3
}

test

EOF
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell will read the script to execute from standard input if you start the shell with its `-s` option. This will stop it from believing the first option is the name of the script file.

So use `bash -s "$1" test1 test2`.

Note that if the script (or any utility called from within the script) is reading from the standard input stream, it will consume the script itself.  This is therefore not suitable for scripts that need the standard input stream for something.  Note also that I used `bash` and not `sh`.  This is necessary to create functions with the non-standard `function` keyword.

Assuming the function (which I will rename into `mytest` as `test` is the name of a built-in command) should output the 2nd and 3rd command line arguments of the script, these need to be passed to the function when you call it.

You may do this by passing *all* the arguments to the function using

```bash
mytest "$@"
```

... or, you could just pass the two that you need (and change the function to output `"$1"` and `"$2"` instead, which would be *its* two first arguments):

```bash
mytest "$2" "$3"
```

You also need to quote all expansions, for example, the `$1` on the command line, as well as `$2` and `$3` in the script itself. See [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)

The script needs to be passed to the shell using a *quoted* here-document or the expansions in the script would be carried out by the invoking shell rather than by the `bash` shell you are starting. You quote a here-document by quoting any part of the initial here-document delimiter.

Taking all these things into consideration, you may want to use the following:

```bash
bash -s "$1" test1 test2 <<'END_SCRIPT'
function mytest {
        echo "$2"
        echo "$3"
}

mytest "$@"
END_SCRIPT
```

Or, with `sh`:

```bash
sh -s "$1" test1 test2 <<'END_SCRIPT'
mytest () {
        echo "$2"
        echo "$3"
}

mytest "$@"
END_SCRIPT
```