# lost variable from bash in yaml gitlab ci

Tags: bash, here-document, gitlab

Need help

I am studying bash and gitlab

can't get it to work

gitlab pipeline .gitlab-ci.yml

```
variables:
    var1: test1
    var2: test2

stages:
  - build


build-job:   
  stage: build   
  script: 
    - |
      bash -s << EOF
      #!/bin/bash
      test1 () {
        echo $var1
        test3=$var1
      }
      test2 () {
        test1
        echo $var2
        echo $test3
      }
      
      test2
      EOF
```

'''

Got  incorrect  answer

'''

> Executing "step_script" stage of the job script 00:00
>
> $ bash -s << EOF # collapsed multi-line command
>
> test1
>
> test2
>
> Job succeeded

lost variable test3

'''

Just the same bash script test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
test1 () {
echo $var1
test3=$var1
   }
test2 () {
test1
echo $var2
echo $test3
     }

test2
```

'''

> $export var1=test1 $export var2=test2
>
> $sh test.sh

got nice answer
This is correct:

> test1
> test2
> test1

but yaml construction has lost variable test3 between functions

I know about run test.sh from gitlab ci,
but i need to run it in yaml as text
How i can do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/723975/116858) to your previous question, the here-document needs to be quoted.  If it is not, the expansion of the variables (and any other expansion) will be carried out by the invoking shell before the `bash -c` script can run.

It would be best if you also double-quoted each expansion inside the `bash -c` script.

Therefore:

```bash
bash -s <<'END_SCRIPT'
test1 () {
    echo "$var1"
    test3=$var1
}
test2 () {
    test1
    echo "$var2"
    echo "$test3"
}
  
test2
END_SCRIPT
```

(Note that since you run the script with `bash` explicitly, there is no need for a `#!`-line.)

If you do not quote the here-document delimiter at the start of the here-document, the shell started for the purpose of running the `bash -c` script would replace all variables.  Assuming `var1` and `var2` exists in the environment as the values `test1` and `test2`, the script that would be executed would be the equivalent of the following:

```bash
bash -s <<END_SCRIPT
test1 () {
    echo "test1"
    test3=test1
}
test2 () {
    test1
    echo "test2"
    echo ""
}
  
test2
END_SCRIPT
```

Comment: just quotes and it works. thank you